# VBA code to get Sharepoint document library Metadata details based on document name

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint-2010

I have below code to open sharepoint 2010 document library's specific document based on filename (library has only excelfiles) but I am unable to read the metadata of that file. I tried with Builtin and custom document properties but there is not luck.

```
Sub OpenSharePointFile(StrSharePointUrl As String, strDocLibrary As String, FileNameWithExt As String)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim SPWorkbook  As Workbook
Dim this        As Workbook
Dim sh          As Shape


Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set SPWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(StrSharePointUrl & strDocLibrary & "\" & FileNameWithExt)
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Set this = ThisWorkbook
If SPWorkbook Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "This product is not available"
    Exit Sub
Else

    'Copy Metadata
    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sht_Input.Name).Range("C3").Value = SPWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Title")
    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sht_Input.Name).Range("C4").Value = SPWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Business Unit")
    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sht_Input.Name).Range("C5").Value = SPWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("ItemNo")
    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sht_Input.Name).Range("C6").Value = SPWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("ECO Type")
    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sht_Input.Name).Range("C7").Value = SPWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("ItemDescription")
    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sht_Input.Name).Range("C8").Value = SPWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Status")
    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sht_Input.Name).Range("C9").Value = SPWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("CasmasUpdate")
    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sht_Input.Name).Range("E3").Value = SPWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("LabelData")
    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sht_Input.Name).Range("E4").Value = SPWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("SpqWhActive")
    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sht_Input.Name).Range("E5").Value = SPWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("I2of5Label")
    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sht_Input.Name).Range("E6").Value = SPWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("TiXHi")
    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sht_Input.Name).Range("E7").Value = SPWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("SpecSent")
    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sht_Input.Name).Range("E8").Value = SPWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("CasmasToYes")
    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sht_Input.Name).Range("E9").Value = SPWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("EcoOwner")

    'Copy ECO Summary:
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sht_Input.Name).Range("B12").Value = SPWorkbook.Sheets(Sht_Input.Name).Range("B12").Value

    'Copy Ref ID
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sht_Input.Name).Range("D14").Value = SPWorkbook.Sheets(Sht_Input.Name).Range("D14").Value

    'Copy THIS ITEM
    SPWorkbook.Sheets(Sht_Input.Name).Range("C14:C74" & lRow).Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sht_Input.Name).Range("C14").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    'Delete from this workbook if available and Copy Shape if available in Sharepoint

    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sht_LCEncodingInfo.Name).Shapes.Count = 2 Then
        For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sht_LCEncodingInfo.Name).Shapes
                If sh.Name <> "Picture 1" Then
                    sh.Delete
                End If
        Next
    End If


    If SPWorkbook.Sheets(Sht_LCEncodingInfo.Name).Shapes.Count = 2 Then
        For Each sh In SPWorkbook.Sheets(Sht_LCEncodingInfo.Name).Shapes
                If sh.Name <> "Picture 1" Then
                    sh.Height = 150 ' 138.96 '1.93"
                    sh.Width = 150 ' 228.24 '3.17"
                    sh.Copy
                    Application.Goto ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sht_LCEncodingInfo.Name).Range("F9")
                    ActiveSheet.Paste
                End If
        Next
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sht_LCEncodingInfo.Name).Range("G2").Select
    End If


    'Activate Input sheet
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sht_Input.Name).Activate
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sht_Input.Name).Range("C3").Select

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    SPWorkbook.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True


    MsgBox "Product Details fetched."

End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: `I am unable to read the metadata of that file` - would you clarify in what way you were unable to do this? Did you get an error? Did the metadata items just return empty string or null? What metadata were you expecting? How do you know the file(s) have the metadata you expect?

Comment: What is the purpose of the block of commented-out code after the `'Copy Metadata` line?

Comment: I have commented out that 'Copy metadata .. because this was giving me an error massage "Title" gives me blank value and others (from Business unit  to till EcoOwner) gives me an error massage "Run-time error = 5: invalid procedure call or argument"  ... I have also tried with CustomDocumentProperties but this is also not working.

Comment: OK. My other questions? This feels like it needs more detail over and above "not working".

Comment: I created a document library in Sharepoint where I stored my excel file with few metadata details like "Business Unit", "ECO Type" etc. there are around 500 files available with metadata in the sharepoint library. Now I want to get file metadata details based on file name or any other key. Do you have any idea to get SharePoint document library metadata details based on file name (This is unique) using VBA code in excel ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using    ActiveWorkbook.ContentTypeProperties("Your column name")
instead of    SPWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Your column name")